# Symfony 5.1 route issue

Tags: symfony, routes, locale

I installed symfony 5.1.3 today and found the route configuration is something broken. I'm not sure if that is intended. But at least it's different from symfony 4.4. I have the follow setting in 4.4 and it works fine.

```
homepage:
   path: 
      en-us: /
      others: /{_locale}/
   controller: App\Controller\IndexController::homepage
   requirements:
      _locale: en-us|zh-cn|zh-hk
```

The above settings allow me to access `domain.com` and other `mydomain.com/en-us`, `mydomain.com/zh-cn` and `mydomain.com/zh-hk` successfully.

But now in symfony 5.1, the above setting does not work now. I believe the _locale with special meaning to the system maybe the root cause. Can anyone give me a help?

Comment: Did you try this from docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#localized-routes-i18n

Comment: Yes, I checked that doc already. That doc doesn’t help for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Localized Routes feature incorrectly.
Keys in `path` are locales. In your case, you have 2 locales: `en-us` and `others`. Try opening `mydomain.com/others` and you will see that it's working.

I suggest splitting this config into 2 routes:

```
homepage:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\IndexController::homepage

homepage_others:
    path: /{_locale}/
    controller: App\Controller\IndexController::homepage
    requirements:
        _locale: en-us|zh-cn|zh-hk
```

Comment: mydomain.com/others does not work for me. I try your solution and it does meet my requirement.  But this solution is somehow generate a small snippet of duplication.  Why symfony 5.1 revert this much desired feature in 4.4?

Comment: Symfony didn't revert this feature. I think you were using this feature, not in a traditional way. Maybe they changed it a bit and your case is not working anymore.